# angular-meteor $templatCache not working

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-templatecache

I'm using *angular-meteor*.

When i try load templates via angular `$templateCache.get` service i get `404/undefined`.

AFAIK, when meteor runs he loads all html files into the `$templateCache`. I can't see this, `$templateCache` will work for me only if i first use `$templateCache.put`.

**not working:**

```
$templateCache.get("table-nested-sc")
```

**working:**

```
$templateCache.put("table-nested-sc","some html")
console.log($templateCache.get("table-nested-sc"))
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!